# Help in understanding step function calculation

Tags: systems-of-equations, signal-processing

[image]

Dear community I would appreciate if you can help me understand these equations. I mean how did he jump from line 1 to line 2? How do u[n] get cancel? Then in the last line where did the "8" come from? And we changed u[n-1] to u[n] once again. Can you please explain it to me? You are my only hope. Thank you.

Comment: The image is very hard to read. Please rewrite the scan in TeX. It will help with getting answers.

Comment: what so hard in it ?

Comment: my only question is how: (-0.9^n)*u(n) + (0.9^(n-1))*u(n-1) = 0.9^(n-1) * (1-0.9) * u(n-1).
How can we cancel u(n) to u(n-1) ?

Comment: Don't listen to him, your picture is nice to read and your question is crystal clear so I upvoted as such. Some users are very impatient with new users, and some might even think that knowing $\LaTeX $  is a requirement for joining this website or they already downvote your question - how well posed it might be. You could join meta.math.stackexchange.com to discuss these matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read and understood correctly then the impulse response given in the first line is

$$h[n]=(1-0.9^n)u[n]-(1-0.9^{n-1})u[n-1]\tag{1}$$

Note that for $n=0$ the first expression on the right-hand side of (1) equals $0$ (because $1-0.9^0=0$), so you can rewrite (1) as

$$\begin{align}h[n]&=(1-0.9^n)u[n-1]-(1-0.9^{n-1})u[n-1]\\
&=(1-0.9^n-1+0.9^{n-1})u[n-1]\\
&=0.9^{n-1}(1-0.9)u[n-1]\\
&=0.9^{n-1}\cdot 0.1\cdot u[n-1]
\end{align}\tag{2}$$

So if I read the first line correctly, then the second line is wrong. I can't see what is on the left-hand side of the third line and how this relates to the first two lines.

Comment: left hand side of third line is : h(n)

Comment: your equation is missing the impulse delta(n)

Comment: ok great great, I understand what you wrote. Now how can we change u[n-1] to u[n]? like in the photo.

Comment: the main point was 0.96

Comment: 0.9^(n) u[n] = 0.9^n u[n-1] << this explain everything.

Comment: @AbdallaBenYounes: No, the statement in your last comment is wrong, because $0.9^0=1$. What *is* correct is $(1-0.9^n)u[n]=(1-0.9^n)u[n-1]$, and this is what I pointed out in my answer.

Comment: 0.9^(n) u(n-1) = 0.9^n u(n) - delta(n) << can we proof this? If yes, we are done.

Comment: @AbdallaBenYounes: If this answer was useful to you, you can accept it by clicking the check mark on its left, and/or upvote it using the arrow.

Comment: useful in some way but still I need to know why the delta(n) is here.

Comment: @AbdallaBenYounes: That's the point: it's wrong!

Comment: @AbdallaBenYounes: I assume that the part of the first line which is cut off of the scan reads $u[n-1]$.

Comment: this assumption is correct.

Comment: @AbdallaBenYounes: OK, then the second line of the scan is wrong, as shown in my answer, because at $n=0$ both parts in the first line become zero.